# How do i redirect back to the form on View with values of text-boxes retained from the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a form on my MVC View. I filled all the fields and submitted it to the controller using razor syntax and not using java-script. On submission, my form got some validation errors like the input was not in the correct format, etc. Now I want to redirect back to the form but the values of text-boxes should not vanish, the page should not reload. I want my form values to retain the values.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! You'll have to provide us your code, otherwise we will not be able to help out much.

Comment: Pass the  model from validation back to your form page ..

Comment: Post your validation model here

Comment: You can just return the appropriate View back from your controller action, and pass it the invalid model. No need to do a redirect

Comment: You need to return View("Viewname",yourmodelobject) in post method if an error occurs.